# How to get and delete record simultaneously in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Some processes at the same time read table. Each process takes on one task. Is it possbile don't use LOCK table in this case ?

```
db.session.execute('LOCK TABLE "Task"')
query = db.session.query(models.Task).order_by(models.Task.ordr).limit(1)
    for row in query:
        task = row
        db.session.delete(row)
 db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By locking table you use `pessimistic` approach to concurrency.

Alterntively, intead of locking the table, you can be `optimistic` about the things going the right way. I would wrap the code to retrieve a task to work on in a continues retry statement with error handling in case the commit fails because some other process already removed this very task this process tried to get.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
def get_next_task():
    session = ...
    task = None
    while not(task):
        try:
            query = session.query(models.Task).order_by(models.Task.ordr).limit(1)
                for row in query:
                    task = row
                    session.delete(row)
            session.commit()
            if not(task):
                return # no more tasks found
        except TODO_FIND_PROPER_EXCEPTION_TO_HANDLE as _exc:
            pass # or log the statement

    # maybe need to make_transient
    return task
```

Whether this solution is *better* will depend on the use case, though.